# Visual Studio Team Services UWP build with AdMediator

Tags: tfs, win-universal-app, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am using AdMediator and Store Engagement SDK in UWP app, using this .ps script before build but still got build failed because it can't find AdMediator and Store Engagement SDK. Anyone got around the problem?

```
Write-Host "Installing Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK..."
$msiPath = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\MicrosoftStoreEngagementAndMonetizationSDK.msi"
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/229b7858-2c6a-4073-886e-cbb79e851211/file/206533/2/MicrosoftStoreEngagementAndMonetizationSDK.msi', $msiPath)
cmd /c start /wait msiexec /i $msiPath /quiet
Write-Host "Installed" -ForegroundColor green
```

Comment: Are you using Hosted Build Agent?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used that SDK, but if installing the MSI referenced in the PowerShell script requires administrative privileges, you will not be able to do it with the hosted build agents. You would either need to create your own build agent (could be an Azure VM) or figure out how to extract what you need from the MSI (e.g., if you only need some DLLs and other key files that don't actually need to be installed).

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft Store Engagement and Monetization SDK requires administrator permission. If you are using Hosted Build Agent, then you cannot install it since hosted build agent does not provide administrator privileges. Check this link for details: [Hosted pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/services/hosted-agent-pool).

> Q: Do any of the processes for your build need administrator
>   privileges?
>
> A: No. Then you can use the hosted pool.

The alternative way would like what Buck said: [deploy your own build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows). With this build agent, you can install the software/SDK you want.